# Getting text box to stay put in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to label two areas of my map in CartoDB. The base map labels two of them already but there are two other regions that need to be labeled. Every time I put a text box over one of the regions, and then move around on the map, the text box moves too.

Comment: Can you explain the problem? The base map is your layer or a cartodb base layer? How are you putting text boxes? These text boxes are labels? Your layer is a polygon layer?

Answer (score 2):

In the CartoDB editor if you "add element" -> "add annotation item" the result will move with the map (e.g. if you place it next to "city x", it will always be next to "city x" even when you pan and zoom the map).

If you "add element" -> "add text item" (or title) the result will be fixed relative to your screen (e.g. if you place it in the upper right corner of the screen it will always be in the upper right corner).